# Reactive form calls custom validator function on construct?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im checking for valid password using isPassVaid, I noticed when the form is construct (formInit) it calls isPassValid, why?

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formInit();
  }  

  formInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [Validators.required, this.isPassVaid]]
    });
  }

  isPassValid(control: FormControl) {
    if (control.value) {
      const regex = '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[^\\da-zA-Z]).{6,10}$';
      const regexp = new RegExp(regex, 'g');
      if (regexp.test(control.value)) {
        return;
      } else {
        return { invalidPass: true };
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `isPassValid` is called every time your formcontrol `password` changes. I guess initialization is no special case ? there might be a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

When the form intializing in ngoninit after the component construction according to life cycle hooks it will call the the isPassValid and it will show invalid bcz u put ' ' as intializing value

So use like below

```
formInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      password: ['', Validators.compose([   Validators.required,    Validators.pattern('  ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[^\\da-zA-Z]).{6,10}$')])]
    });
```

}